# How to use correctly the "Scene" actuator

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, scene

I've read in an answer here that in order to suspend-resume a scene correctly you need an overlay scene.

In my case I have a main scene and an overlay scene. I use the overlay scene to pause-unpause the main scene.

Now I wish to change from the main scene to other secondary scenes and back(resume). So I send a message to my overlay_scene_camera_obj to suspend the main scene and set a new scene(secondary scene). My problem is that when I want to go back, I send again a message from an object in my secondary scene to my overlay_scene_camera_obj but nothing happens.

At first I thought I would need to add the "overlay" scene to the secondary scene too, but it did not work. But still I suspect the "overlay" scene goes off during the change from my main(+overlay) to secondary, so any messages sent to overlay from secondary don't get through.

So is there a useful documentation/thread or can someone tell me what I might be missing.

p.s. I thought someone had posted here or in blenderartists couple of years back regarding this actuator and its "problems". But I couldn't find the thread.

Comment: Your overlay scene sets the secondary scene?

Comment: Yes. An event happens in the main scene, and a message gets sent to the camera in the overlay scene, and the logic bricks in the overlay camera set the secondary scene.

Comment: As far as I understand your setup you would either get three scenes (first, overlay + second as background), or your get two scenes (first and second as replacement of overlay). I suggest to do "set scene" on the first scene that it gets replaced by the second scene. The overlay scene needs to resume both scenes.

Comment: If I did not lose you, this is what I do. I "set" the seconday scene. My current setup is : mainScene+OverlayScene --> "set" secondaryScene and "suspend" mainScene --> "resume" mainScene.  All events happen in main/secondary scene and messages are sent to OverlayScene and that OverlayScene handles all scene actuators.

Comment: Overall, your question sounds pretty much a similar question from the same day: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78968/bge-switching-between-scenes. Your question is more focused on how to use the scene managing, but the issue might still be the "return to scene". Nevertheless the answer might help you a bit.

Comment: You were right. I got what I needed in the first paragraph. Thanks and I ll try to mark this as duplicate or something similar.