# BGE Switching between scenes

Tags: game-engine

I have two scenes which i want to switch between when a collide sensor is activated. If i use a 'remove scene'+ 'add scene' the first scene cannot be returned to. If i use a 'suspend scene' + 'set scene' the first scene cannot be returned to. If i use a 'suspend scene' + 'add scene over lay' the transition works but you are still able to see the first scene behind the second...

Is there any way of getting around this? New to blender, sorry if it is really simple!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is simple, just create a button that will "set scene" to return to your desired scene.

For your fixed button *GUI* instead of *Add Overlay* or *Background Scene*,

Select the object goto *Object > Make links > Object to Scene*, select the scene you want to link to, and it will appear there automatically.

To change the function of the "linked objects" , make a *Single User*

Answer (score 0):

You can never "return" to a scene. Either the scene is present or it is not.

## Scene switching

You can switch from scene A to scene B. This means the scene A is gone. It is gone for ever and will not come back. You can switch to another scene A that is created from the same sources (blend file). This new A scene will look equal to the old scene A but is a complete new scene. Any changes of the old scene A will not be considered unless you apply it to the new scene A too.

You can't "return". But you can make it look like a "return".

This is typically used on save/load. This is much more extreme than your situation. Not only the scenes are gone, the complete game session is gone.

The goal is the same, after loading it should look like the game continued where it was saved (sort of time travel).

Unfortunately storing and restoring the status of each single object within a scene is complicated and you need Python to do that for your. Details are too much for this question and should be asked separately.

## Multiple scenes

You can have multiple scenes at the same time. This is useful when working with HUD, Menus etc..

All these scenes will be rendered. The order depends on how you add the scenes. Typically you start with one scene. You can add an overlay scene (rendered before the scene that add it) or you add a background scene (rendered after the scene that add it).

A background scene will only be seen at pixels that would show the background of the overlay scene. This means an overlay scene might completely cover the background scene.

You can use this to your advantage. 
A) cover the background scene completely
B) let the camera of the background scene show empty space

## Scene suspending

Suspending a scene means the animation, logic and physics of that scene is not performed anymore.

It will still be rendered!

Suspending can be used in conjunction with multiple scenes, to stop the logic  on the "hidden" scene.